# When is it the good time to label formulas and how to organize the labels?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

When writing an article in LaTeX, I don't usually have a specific formula in mind that might be refereed to later. So I have to label all of them. I find manually adding `\label{}` slow.  Is there a quick way to put `\label{}` quickly in an organizable clear way?

Moreover, if I have already used the label `sec1-eq1`, `sec1-eq2`, (and suppose I have already referred to them somewhere else,) but I need to put a new formula between these two, then I will have to use something like `sec1-eq1-1` for it. What I want is to change `sec1-eq2` to `sec1-eq3` then I have the right label for this new formula. Is there a way to change `\label{sec1-eq2}` to `\label{sec1-eq3}` so that all the `\ref{sec1-eq2}` will automatically become `\ref{sec1-eq3}`?

Comment: never use _numbers_ in the label text it defeats the whole point of the label system. (This question is a duplicate, I'll see if I kind find the previous answers)

Comment: you should use labels like `\label{fermat}` and reference as `\ref{fermat}` then it does not matter how many equations you add or remove, the reference works and latex will put in the correct number.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Thank you very much for the link! Would you say that using `showkey` is the correct way to organize/manipulate the labels?

Comment: It's a possibility, as I wrote it I can't say if it is any good:-)